# Git branching guidelines

Tags: git

In my work environment, first we had a release planned for October and so we created the below structure

Master --> Develop --> feature

Changes are currently in feature branch for October release.

Now we are getting another project for August release. So I have the following options

Option1 :
1) Don't merge the change of feature branch created for Oct release to develop branch
2)Branch out another feature branch from Develop for August release
3) Once the August release is done, merge the changes to develop branch and October feature branch

Option 2:
As we plan to merge the changes from feature branch (Oct) to Develop branch frequently for SIT deployment
1) Branch out another Develop branch from Master for August 
2) And then create a feature branch for August release from this Develop branch
3) Merge the changes to Develop branch regularly. After release, merge the changes to Master,Develop branch of October and feature branches

Option 3 :
Creating a release branch

Master --> Develop --> Release --> Feature

1) Create a Release branch specific for releases and manage merging

Please let me know which approach is correct and will have minimum merging requirement.

~Thanks

Comment: Are you saying you have a *single* branch called `feature` which is everything planned for the October release?

Answer (score 2):

> *Please let me know which approach is correct...*

There's no correct approach, but some are better than others.

> *...and will have minimum merging requirement.*

Paradoxically, you want to be branching and merging *more* frequently, but with less change.

Long-lived branches which accumulate a lot of changes accumulate complexity making them hard to qa, manage, and merge. Months between releases also accumulate a lot of features that have to be dropped on users simultaneously. These all make the merge, integration, and release process slow and complex.

Then you have the sort of problem right now: you have an incomplete, large October release branch. The release schedule has been wielded into the development process. Now you're being asked to cut an August release, what do you do with all that code in the October branch? It's inflexible.

---

Instead, have a single long-lived branch that everything is developed on. Develop features individually in isolated, short-lived feature branches. QA them before merging. This gives you a single long-lived branch which is *always* ready for release.

It might look something like this.

```
                      I - J   L - M - N [feature1]
                     /     \ /
A - B - C ----- F - G ----- K [master]
         \     /             \
          D - E               O - P [feature2]
```

This shows two completed features, `D - E` and `I - J`, have already passed QA and been merged into master. Since QA has already been done on the feature branches, master is deployed to production. There are two open feature branches. The developers of those branches periodically run `git rebase master` so they are up to date with the latest fully tested code from `master`. This simplifies the merge process by always keeping their branch on the tip of `master` and dealing with conflicts incrementally rather than in a big chunk at the end.

Notice there are no direct commits to master, it only changes via a feature branch merge. This means master is always tested, reliable, and ready to deploy. Individual features in progress don't interfere with each other and can rely on a stable master branch; if something breaks they know it's because of their work, not because someone broke the dev branch.

Now you can release whenever you want, `master` is always ready to go. The release schedule and development process are independent of each other. You can deploy from `master` on a set schedule or you as soon as something is merged.

You'd work on features for the October release as individual branches and QA and merge them. If there's a sudden change of priority, like a set of features for an August release, you shift work to those features just as before. When the August deadline hits, `master` is ready to go and gets deployed.

If there are October features you don't want deployed yet in August leave the code in, but turn them off with a configuration switch.

This avoids having to manage multiple, long-lived branches with overlapping changes in parallel and merging between them. Instead you have multiple, short-lived branches each for a single feature. If you want to track what's been deployed, use tags, not branches.